# How to map a table row to multiple parent rows using mapping table?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a `master_data` with all types of data such as `Learning`, `Program` and `Course`. Another table `mapping` tells you parent/child relationship.

Here is the grouping/heirarichy

Learning -> Programs -> Course

> A Learning may have multiple Programs, a Program may have multiple
>   Courses. Also, a Program can be part of multiple Learnings and a
>   Course can be part of multiple Programs.

How to bring the data by keeping an extra column some thing like `parent` to identify a parent, so that it helps to group the rows.

**Master_data**

```
    id  title                           description type
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    1   How to Present                  some info   Learning
    2   Securing Data                   more info   Learning
    3   Preparation plan                more info   Program
    4   Protecting System               info        Program
    5   Presentation mediums            some info   Program
    6   know the importance             some info   Course
    7   Notice the key concepts         some info   Course
    8   Presenting in PPT               some info   Course
    9   Presenting in Video format      some info   Course
    10  Update the System               some info   Course
    11  Chose a Strong password         some info   Course
```

**Mapping**

```
    id  learning_id  program_id      course_id
    ---------------- ----------- --------------
    1   1               3               6
    2   1               5               6
    3   1               3               7
    4   1               5               8
    5   1               5               9
    6   2               4               6
    7   2               4               10
    8   2               4               11
```

**Result**

```
    id  title                           description type       parent
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1   How to Present                  some info   Learning   1 (itself)
    3   Preparation plan                more info   Program    1
    5   Presentation mediums            some info   Program    1
    6   know the importance             some info   Course     3 
    7   Notice the key concepts         some info   Course     3
    8   Presenting in PPT               some info   Course     5
    9   Presenting in Video format      some info   Course     5
```

Here, Programs 3,5 are part of learning 1. Courses 6,7 are belongs to Program 3 and 8,9 belongs to Program 5

**Queries of Above in Mysql**

```
    CREATE TABLE `master_data` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `description` TEXT NOT NULL,
      `type` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


    INSERT INTO `master_data` (`id`, `title`, `description`, `type`) VALUES 
('1', 'How to Present', 'some info', 'Learning'),
('2', 'Securing Data', 'few more info', 'Learning'),
('3', 'Preparation plan', 'informatoin abt this', 'Program'),
('4', 'Protecting System', 'security info', 'Program'),
('5', 'Presentation mediums', 'some info', 'Program'),
('6', 'You should know the importance', 'some info', 'Course'),
('7', 'Notice the key concepts', 'some info', 'Course'),
('8', 'Presenting in PPT', 'some info', 'Course'),
('9', 'Presenting in Vedio format', 'some info', 'Course'),
('10', 'Update the System', 'some info', 'Course'),
('11', 'Chose a Strong password', 'some info', 'Course');


    CREATE TABLE `mapping` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `learning_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `program_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `course_id` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


    INSERT INTO `mapping` (`id`, `learning_id`, `program_id`, `course_id`) VALUES 
('1', '1', '3', '6'),
('2', '1', '5', '6'),
('3', '1', '3', '7'),
('4', '1', '5', '8'),
('5', '1', '5', '9'),
('6', '2', '4', '6'),
('7', '2', '4', '10'),
('8', '2', '4', '11');
```

Comment: please add a sample result to the question.

Comment: You should put learning, program and course into three different tables and establish foreign key constraints between them.

Comment: Can you also add expected output for your sample data

Comment: @MaxGaurav, @M Khalid I have updated the expected result

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with PostgreSQL, right?

Comment: @Strawberry, I am implementing this model in Postgres. But i defined this example in MySQL.

Comment: It is rather simple to create 3 tables from that one table, then proceed with Laurenz's suggestion.

Comment: In your `mapping` table course 6 belongs to programs 3, 5 and 4. But in your result `parent_id` of 6 is 3. Why not 4 or 5?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Also, your question is unclear: "How to bring the data by keeping an extra column some thing like parent to identify a parent, so that it helps to group the rows." Please use enough sentences and phrases to clearly say what you mean. Don't cram a bunch of words into one sentence.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it with the help of UNION clause:

```
select id,title,description,type,id from master_data where type='Learning'
UNION
select program_id,title,description,type,learning_id from master_data md, mapping m where md.id=m.program_id
UNION
select course_id,title,description,type,program_id from master_data md, mapping m where md.id=m.course_id;
```

You should have proper constraints and indexes in place for data accuracy and good performance.

Answer (score 0):

This query will solve the problem, it's not elegant but gets the job done

```
SELECT *,
(CASE
  WHEN type = 'Learning'
    THEN id
  WHEN type = 'Program'
    THEN (SELECT a.learning_id
       FROM mapping AS A
       WHERE a.program_id = id
       LIMIT 1)
  WHEN type = 'Course'
    THEN (SELECT a.program_id
       FROM mapping AS A
       WHERE a.course_id = id
       LIMIT 1)
  END
  ) AS parent
FROM master_data;
```

**Suggestion**
Best to create indexes at the correct position if the result will be a very big list.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav garu.